# How to call a variable in the middle of a word in Powershell

Tags: variables, powershell, windows-xp

If, for example, I wanted to insert a variable in the middle of a non-spacing string/word, how would I do this?

```
$i=First
ECHO ThisIsMy$iVariable
```

How would I populate $i correctly to make it look like

```
ThisIsMyFirstString
```

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/howto-writing-good-titles

Comment: @Nacereddine you should've added Powershell at the end then. You should read the WHOLE post if you're going to link it =/

Comment: Nice catch. My bad, but since you already tagged your question properly I figured it wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Now if I could only get someone to put answers... is there a post for that? "HOWTO Force people to answer your questions".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure that this is what you're looking for but you can insert the value of `$i` in a non space separated string like follows :

```
$i = "first"
echo "ThisIsMy$($i)Variable"
```

This will output :

```
ThisIsMyfirstVariable
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I would've never thought to put an additional $ behind the variable. I tried ($i) too =(.  Tanx a bunch @Nacereddine.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it this way (less punctuation):

```
$i = "first"
echo "ThisIsMy$i`Variable"
```

Comment: is ` the break character in powershell?

Comment: It's the escape character.  Most languages use a backslash (\), but that symbol is used heavily in the shell already, so they went with the back-tick (`).